# Accessing text from entry in a jquery.ui dialog box

Tags: forms, text, jquery-ui-dialog

How does one get text data out of a jquery.ui dialog box?
I've singled out the call that isn't working, and included all the script links to show what I'm using.  Although the text entry into the dialog box works, it doesn't pass to the form that contains it.  As you see, I've tried to copy it to a field outside the dialog box and that doesn't work. What I really want to do is post it to the action page like the other data in the form.

Here's the url: http://dev.bizzocall.com/cp-BizzoActiveButtonSIMPLE.php

CODE:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/bizCon.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
mysql_select_db($database_bizCon, $bizCon);
$query_buttonPrefsSet = "SELECT buttonprefs.iduserid, buttonprefs.btop, buttonprefs.bleft, buttonprefs.bcolor, buttonprefs.blabel, buttonprefs.newvisitors, buttonprefs.bdelay, buttonprefs.brepeats, buttonprefs.btype, buttonprefs.bphonetarget FROM buttonprefs ORDER BY buttonprefs.iduserid DESC LIMIT 1";
$buttonPrefsSet = mysql_query($query_buttonPrefsSet, $bizCon) or die(mysql_error());
$row_buttonPrefsSet = mysql_fetch_assoc($buttonPrefsSet);
$totalRows_buttonPrefsSet = mysql_num_rows($buttonPrefsSet);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<title>Bizzo Control Panel</title>
<link href="css/plan.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/BizzocallPopup.css" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/cpanel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/BizzocallPopup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Draggable/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="Draggable/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="Draggable/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="Draggable/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                // Dialog           
                $('#labelStgdialog').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 400,
                    buttons: {
                        "OK": function() { 

                            $(this).dialog("close"); 
                        } 
                    }
                });

                // Dialog Link
                $('#labelSetgbtn').click(function(){
                    $('#labelStgdialog').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });

            });

            $('#enterlabel').change(function() {
             $("input#blabel").val($("input#enterlabel;").val());
});
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contentWrapper">
  <form action="cp-BizzoEmbedCodeSIMPLE.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="buttonprefform" target="_top">
    <div id="labelSetgbtn" class="button gray LabelSettings"><a href="#">LABEL SETTINGS</a></div>
    <div id="labelStgdialog" class="DialogBox">
      <div class="boldtxt">ENTER YOUR CUSTOM LABEL</div>
      <div class="labeltxtblack">CALL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
      <input name="enterlabel" type="text" id="enterlabel" class="enterlabel" value=" > 10 char "  maxlength="9" length="10"/>
      <div class="clearer"></div>
      <div class="space10"></div>
      <div class="bcpopuptop">
        <div class="bcsquare">
          <div class="innersquare"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="btnlabeltxt">CALL NOW</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input id="blabel" name="blabel" type="text" value="<?php echo strtoupper($row_buttonPrefsSet['blabel']); ?>" />
    <button name="mysubmitbutton" id="mysubmitbutton" type="submit" class="createbizzobutton"> </button>
  </form>
</div>
<!--END contentwrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

$("input#blabel").val($("input#enterlabel;").val());

should be

$("input#blabel").val($("input#enterlabel").val());

?

Comment: Good catch!  I had to read through the code a few times to see that lil ';' sucker!  But it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I found a way to do it.  Let me share it in hopes it'll help someone out.
I put the <form> tag AFTER the div that calls the dialog box (id "labelStgdialog). This dialog box has a text input field (not a form field) with id="enterlabel". Then, I changed the code for the "OK" button of the dialog box to copy field id "enterlabel" to the form field id 'blabel' which is inside the form and bound to the database.

When I get the rest of the page fully working, I'll post a link.